# How do enemies scale with the player level?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In Fallout: New Vegas, enemies get stronger as you level up. But which of their stats increase, and in which scale?

Comment: When I was around level 20+, I fought the Legendary Deathclaw on Very Hard and it would kill me in two to three hits. Now, at level 46, an ordinary Deathclaw kills me in four hits on Normal. :P

Comment: They got stronger?  I thought they all had certain levels in certain areas of the game.  You'd know if you shouldn't be there if you were nowhere near their levels.

Comment: @Jeff: There's level scaling in New Vegas, but it's within ranges -  enemies do have certain minimum and maximum values on their levels/stats to maintain a variety of difficulty levels in different regions.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: Ah I guess that would explain it then, when I played the game, I spent a lot of time in one area to level up a lot before moving on.  I'd usually be 5-10 levels above the enemies in the next area.  So you could see why that would confuse me.  :)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz do you have any information over these scale ranges?

Comment: And I've just seen that Deathclaws at the Divide scale until level 50: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deathclaw_(Fallout%3A_New_Vegas)#Deathclaw_.28The_Divide.29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enemies level up kind of like the player character. Many have a cap on how high in level they can get and some have a floor value which is their minimum level.

What stats increase depends on the class of the npc.
If you fire up the constructionset thingie for fallout and look at how the npc's / monsters are scripted its easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Enemy leveling is the entire basis of the Logan's Loophole trait. Many people believed you were making your character weaker by missing out on those extra perks, etc. Due to the wasteland leveling with the character and the benefits of chems with no UMON (addiction) it completely compensates for the lost levels and perks. When you can pop chems like candy for better SPECIAL stats, DT, rad resistance, energy resistance, etc and have them last an absurd amount of time with day tripper challenge, chemist perk, etc then you become just as overpowered versus your similarly level locked enemies than someone that is level 45+.

Answer (score -2):

The guy above me is wrong. I played fallout for very long maybe like 400 hours I don't know how long exactly, but there is no level scaling mobs don't level its just like an MMORPG there are strong mobs in this place and weak mobs in this place. Most mobs re-spawn after a long time. Like there are fire ants in some dry lake even if your'e level 45 cap they're still the same fire ants. and there are deathclaws at some mine place they are still the same deathclaws if you're level 1.

Comment: Actually Jonas B is correct. While the class of NPC is dependent on location (as you describe), the "variant" (read: level) is based on the level of the player. For instance, Spore Carriers can be normal, or brutes, or runts: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Spore_carrier Similarly, Deathclaws can be babies, young, blind, normal, legendary etc.